# When I mount my SD card to my PC, it doesn't appear in my computer

Tags: sd-card

When I plug in my memory card, the drive isn't assigned a letter, etc. Thus I am not able to access it from *[My Computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#Virtual_folders)*. When I run a partition analysis program it picks up the drive, so I am sure that the card is working. What's the problem?

Comment: Does it show up in disk management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem. This is perfectly normal. For regular disk partitions, unless a filesystem is mounted and assigned a drive letter, it will not show up under `My Computer`. If you want to access a partition from `My Computer`, assign it a drive letter using the disk manager. (Type `diskmgmt.msc` into the `Run` bar.)

Comment: You may also have a broken filesystem on that partition. If assigning a drive letter yields a partition that shows as "RAW" or otherwise shows in `My Computer` but you still can't access it, try reformatting the partition. The usual warnings about lost data apply.